# bootstrap : Align two div inside td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which have td column named action and I want to display two icon for remove and edit actions and display them next to each other.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="row">
  <div class="delete" (click)="supprimer(element.id)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"title="Supprimer">
              <a (click)="supprimer(element.id)">
                <img src="/assets/img/clear.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
 <div class="edit" (click)="edit(element.id)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit">
  <a (click)="supprimer(element.id)">
   <img src="/assets/img/edit.png" alt="">
  </a>
 </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: try setting both `div`s to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simply write css for the div's immediate parent,
`td.row {display: flex;}`

Answer (score 0):

a `<div>` defaults `display: block`, this will make the width of the block fill the space remaining. (If you don't use it in combination of display: flex).

I'm no Angular expert but you have a click event on both the `<a>` and the `<div>`.
an `<a>` element is already a `display: inline` by default so they should appear next to each other. Removing the div's all together should be the solution.

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="row">
  <a class="delete" (click)="supprimer(element.id)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Supprimer">
    <img src="/assets/img/clear.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a class="edit" (click)="edit(element.id)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit">
    <img src="/assets/img/edit.png" alt="">
  </a>
</td>
```